# One link for Firefox and Chrome add-ons?

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-extension

I have add-on for Chrome and Firefox, they are same just for different browsers. Is it possible to have one link/button for the add-on, once user clicks it, it will be recognized which browser user is on and opens Chrome vs Firefox add-on.
It would be possible to have in html 2 buttons and hide one for each browser, but I would like to have just one button.
Thanks!

Comment: sure it is possible. So detect the browser and show and hide the button.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

Comment: Thanks for answer @epascarello, so no other way as just to show/hide buttons for respective browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract browser name from navigator.userAgent then set needed link

```
<a href="#" id="link">Add-on Link</a>
<script>

    var link = document.querySelector("#link");
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;

    if (userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > 0) {
        link.setAttribute("href", "https://www.mozilla.org");
    } else if (userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") > 0) {
        link.setAttribute("href", "https://google.com");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks much for your answer!